# I can't find extends Component in my Apps.js file after installing React

Tags: reactjs

I followed the installation guide in https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_getstarted.asp to install React on my system. But after installation, I followed their instructions to open the `App.js` file only to discover that my own `Apps.js` has

```
function App() { ... }
```

while the one shown on w3schools website has

```
class App extends Component { ... }
```

Please is there a problem with my installation?

Answer (score 2):

`class` is just a special function, and `extends` means it's using other properties of another function.

just change `functionApp(){..}` to `class App extends Component{..}`

as well as adding

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

to the top of your page and it should work exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dig down more to get the exact knowledge of both the Components as both of them are equally important. 
Class based components are state based components means you can change the state (data accordingly)

> class App extends React.Component{...}

but in functional component,

> function App(props) { ... }

you cannot change the data directly here and whatever is coming in props value you can just show that thus it is called stateless component.You should use functional components if you are writing a presentational component which doesn’t have its own state or needs to access a lifecycle hook. Otherwise you can stick to class components

For more: https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108 https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/react-functional-components/

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a problem with your installation. React basically has 2 types of Components: Class and Function. The one created using create-react-app is a Function component whereas w3schools uses Class component for most tutorials. You can find more about them here: [W3Schools: React Components](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_components.asp)

Learn about both of them and use whichever you want according to your use case.